# Missing tags while using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm using beautifulsoup to parse html file. However, some tags are missing by find_all() method. The html link is [YARN-8569](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/commit/d07e873b7db6cb317eccb4768607c1afb505c99b)

[image]

The code is here:

```
for tag in soup.find_all('div', class_='js-diff-progressive-container'):
    print 1
    for div in tag.find_all('div'):
        id = div.get('id')
        if id:
            id = id.split('-')
            print id
            if id[0] == 'diff':
                div2 = div.find_all('div')
                class_div = div2[0]
                if class_div.get('data-path'):
                    changed_class.append(class_div.get('data-path'))
```

However, I can only open the first div tag with class of 'js-diff-progressive-container' and get its child tag. For the second one I will get a dev whose class name is 'js-diff-progressive-retry'(I can't find this in the html file). Also, I can't get its child tags.

The output is

[image]

I use lxml as my htmlparser(which is the answer suggested by others but it still doesn't work)

Comment: The name "js-diff-progressive-container" sounds like it will not be delivered at once when accessed but instead bit by bit as the user scrolls to that position (which seems not to happen when you access the URL using your python program). However I don't have an idea how to trigger the delivery of the full HTML code at once. Github has an API, maybe this is gives you a cleaner solution in the long run.

Comment: That makes sense to me. Do you know the exact Github API that I can get all the html code? @0x6d64

Comment: Now I'm trying github API, hope it works. Thx a lot!!

Comment: @0x6d64: please add an answer to that effect